# questions about lists on c++

Tags: c++, list

Consider a List of strings that contains the following strings in the order given:

```
"bob" "ann" "sue" "ned":   [0]   [1]   [2]   [3] respectively
```

Give the contents of the List after each operation.

```
a. list.insert(2, "bob");
b. list.insert(5, "ann");
c. list.remove(0);
d. list.remove(3);

I got...bob, ann, bob, sue, ned;
 bob, ann, bob, sue, ned, ann;
ann, bob, sue, ned, ann;
ann, bob, sue, ann
```

is this correct?

Comment: Why do you suspect that these results may not be correct?

Comment: Pretty simple: try it out. Next point: being a bit more precise than "list" would be quite helpful. And a quick look at the docs would answer the question as well.

Comment: I suspected the results may not be correct mainly because of b. I know that there will now be 4 items on the list, but I didn't know if we could reference of 5th index if it does not exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [MCVE].

Comment: AFAIK the first argument to insert function is an iterator. How can you give a integer value there?? Again remove function accepts the value to be removed as the argument and not the index.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/) and you will get to know how to insert values. Use the `iterator` to insert values. The value will be inserted just before the current iterator position. Since `iterator.end()` will be the last position you cannot go beyond that. Use `push_back()` to insert the element at the end.